# Remove small cracks on a black and white photo in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I have a photo that is not of very high quality and and these kinds of small cracks all over its surface.

[image]

Is there a way to reduce this effect?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you share the entire photo?  It's difficult to differentiate between what parts are cracks, and which are details.  All I can really see is some sort of texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use luminance noise reduction, but the overall result will be to lose detail.

If that is part of a much larger image, sharpening or using high-pass on the result might regain some apparent edge detail, but on that small segment it's hard to tell.

Quick bluff through Photoshop, no re-sharpening as I don't know what needs to be sharpened from so little information…

[image]

I ran a high-pass too, but with no real hope of knowing which detail needs to be recovered it's a total guess…

[image]

A better guess could be made from the full image - blur or blank out any personal details, faces etc, if you need to.